# Let's Encrypt SSL install error on apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm trying to install ssl on multiple virtual hosts and domains on same IP. I am using multiple .conf files for this.

Already have three working domains on this IP with SSL. But while trying to install ssl on one more domain with command:

`certbot-auto --apache -d mydomain.com -d www.mydomain.com`

get this error:

> The selected vhost would conflict with other HTTPS VirtualHosts within
>   Apache. Please select another vhost or add ServerNames to your
>   configuration. VirtualHost not able to be selected.

Here is the configuration I have in `mydomain.conf`

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain/
               ServerName mydomain.com
               ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
            <Directory /var/www/mydomain/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
            </Directory>

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

Comment: Presumably you have unique `ServerName`s defined for each VirtualHost (and your main server config)? _Aside:_ That mod_rewrite redirect would seem to be in error (when used outside of the `<VirtualHost *:80>`)? You should be checking against `HTTP_HOST`, rather than `SERVER_NAME` - although that may not make much difference depending on how `UseCanonicalName` is set. (Ideally, you would use a `Redirect` in the appropriate `VirtualHost` container instead of mod_rewrite here.)

Comment: and what should I take as `appropriate VirtualHost container`? are you specifically talking about SNI ?